# Text display Windows 10 fix

Tags: windows-10

[image]

As you can see from the attached image text has orange blotches on this Quicken display running on Windows 10 with all the latest maintenance applied. How can I remove the orange blotches?

Thanks!

Comment: Clean your display? I don't see anything that's orange? Maybe try to circle what you actually mean?

Comment: The clarity of text on Windows at higher resolutions and higher DPI is entirely left to the developer

Answer (score 0):

These are results of ClearType not working properly. ClearType is a font smoothing algorithm that uses sub-pixel antialiasing to render crispier text. ClearType makes some assumptions about physical pixel layout of your display. When these assumptions aren't correct, some artifacts such as these may appear.

Some colored tints on edges are expected to appear with ClearType enabled. When you're not so close to the screen, they will blend into fonts and improve perceived font smoothness. They shouldn't be that articulate, though.

Open the Start menu and type *cleartype*, an item called *Adjust ClearType Text* will appear. Choose it. The system will guide you through the calibration process.

Comment: I have calibrated ClearType, but it does not fix the problem.

Comment: With ClearType turned off the problem disappears, but text is very grainy in appearance. It seems that Microsoft really mucked up text display with Windows 10. I did not have these problems with Windows 7.